# Quick Shine polish left haze on floor

Tags: flooring, cleaning

I used [this product](https://www.quickshinefloors.com/shop/hardwood-floors/hardwood-floor-luster/) and it caught all of the dust and now I can’t get it off of my floors. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get this stuff off?

[image: quick shine]

[image: quick shine]

Comment: Did you follow the directions?  Camauba is a type of wax usually.  So it seems to be more of a polish than just a duster.

Comment: I can't tell from way back here, but I'm guessing that either your floor was very dirty, you overworked the product as it was drying, or there was some reaction with the existing surface treatment. Please revise your post to tell us more about your work and the conditions. It's hard to say much with what little we know.

Comment: What kind of surface finish was on the floor before you applied this stuff?

Comment: If this is a wax, you may need to actively buff the surface to remove haze. The directions should include that step if so.

Comment: @brhans Makes a crucial point, here. Although the manufacturer's website says it's compatible with all hardwood, the manufacturer (in comments on their website) admits "Quick Shine is a water borne polymer formulated only intended for use on factory sealed or polyurethane floors."

So if your hardwood floor had a shellac finish, you would expect this exact outcome. Water creates a haze on a shellac finish. To improve water resistance of shellac, you'd want to use a paste wax (or coat it with polyurethane).

Added for posterity, to help people looking for options to wax their shellac floor.

Answer (score 1):

The product instructions call for you to clean all dust, dirt, grime and pet hair from the floor first, then apply the product.

[image]

Call the manufacturer's help line to learn how to remove the product from your floor finish so you can start over.

Image credit: Amazon.com